# Node.js cluster module

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

please help. I'm using nodejs cluster module: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.18/api/cluster.html. I have the following code:

run.js

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    require('os').cpus().forEach(function () {
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
    require('./worker.js');
}
```

worker.js

```
var http = require('http'),
    connect = require('connect'),
    sio = require('socket.io'),
    // create server
    app = connect(),
    server = http.createServer(app);

server.listenPort(80);

var io = sio.listen(server);
// io.sockets.on ....
```

All workers listen 80 port. Each connection serves a random worker(?). Can I switch worker, where user has connected?

*sorry my bad english*

Answer (score 1):

If you really needed to switch you could use sockets / socket.io to communicate between your clusters and send your work around.

Otherwise, you can't. But just curious - why would you want to?

Comment: I'm created game without communication between workers, all data saved in js objects in memory. Now, I want launch some workers with cluster module, but if two users connect to different workers, he cant play together.

I know, that I can use 'process.send' in worker and 'worker.on' in master process, but switching user worker is more simply and faster solution for me.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be using clusters with your game then

Comment: Maybe, but without it, i can't use more than one cpu core, sad

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way.  Instead of keeping shared js objects directly in memory, store them in a memory-mapped store like memcached or redis so that they can be easily accessed by all workers.

Comment: @skyman Your application code should be stateless, the state information should be in a common place such as fast stores like redis, memcached

Comment: I think, u right, but select right architecture is very hard for me (

Answer (score 0):

You should look into WebRTC which enables peer-to-peer connection which is great for multi-player games.

My 2 cents.